# What does it mean when a signal is ignored?

Tags: signals

What does it mean when a signal is ignored ?

Comment: Read https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html first.

Answer (score 1):

Signal handling in Linux is done "under the covers" with the glibc library of system calls. According to [gnu library documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html):

> The SIGTERM signal is a generic signal used to cause program termination. Unlike SIGKILL, this signal can be blocked, handled, and ignored. It is the normal way to politely ask a program to terminate.

I'll attempt to define the terms *blocked*, *handled*, and *ignored* below (code examples don't include error handling, so be aware ):

**Blocked**: 
Each process that runs in Linux is given a signal mask on process creation. The *sigprocmask* function call can be used to block or unblock signals - with blocked signals being queued, so that they can be handled later when the process unblocks them. For example, to block SIGTERM using standard signal related system calls (from The Linux Programming Interface, by Michael Kerrisk) -

```
    sigset_t blockSet, savedSigMask;
    sigemptyset(&blockSet); /* initialize empty */
    sigaddset(&blockSet, SIGTERM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &blockSet, &savedSigMask);

/* process will not be interrupted by SIGTERM, which can be restored later*/
```

**Ignored**:
 Similarily, a signal can be ignored with the sigaction syscall and the SIG_IGN flag- ie the process will not be interrupted when it receives the signal and the signal will not be queued - by using the system call *sigaction*:

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER; /* Dont block the signal when it's handler is running */
sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
```

**Handled**:
sigaction can also be used to define a function that is called when the signal is received. This is kind of best practice for receiving SIGTERM, allowing your process to close gracefully.

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_sigaction = functionp; /* functionp is your handler function */
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER | SA_SIGINFO;
sigaction(signo, &sa, NULL;
```

You can use a signal handler for SIGTERM so that it will not cause your process to exit, but this is not usually what a SIGTERM handler would be used for. Another thing to note is that on systems running *systemd*, systemd will send KILL signal to a program that receives SIGTERM and then doesn't exit, so to prevent that systemd has to be configured to allow your process to ignore SIGTERM.

Comment: @linuxuser so, purely hypothetically, lets say chrome is about to do some input/ output, like read from a socket; and it doesn't want to be interrupted: it blocks SIGTERM, intending to restore it later; but while SIGTERM is blocked, it crashes: sending a SIGTERM would have no effect at this point and now only a SIGKILL can terminate the process.

Comment: ok, no problems but if its a big question probably better to raise a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

SIGTERM is used to notify a process that it has to stop its execution, the process then decides what to do, usually cleaning up resources and peacefully stop its execution, so the 3 scenarios are up to the process developers.

If you want to kill, no matter what, a process, you have to use SIGKILL `kill -9` which is not even delivered to the running process.